# merge into statement used to work previously , but now not

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a strange behavior with a merge into statement in Oracle. Actually,few days ago,  my statement used to work perfectly and the requested column is being updated. However, as of today I found out it is no longer updating the column. I am getting confused if this is environment related issue or a problem related the query it self. Can you advise please ?

Query :

```
merge into Currency_table CURR
using (
      SELECT CURR.rowid as RID, M_SYSTEM 
      FROM Currency_table CURR, Trade_ext TRN_EXT, TradeGen TRN, CONTRACT CNT 
      WHERE CNT.M_REFERENCE= 123
      AND CNT.M_REFERENCE = TRN.M_CONTRACT 
      AND TRN.M_NumB = TRN_EXT.M_C_REF
      AND TRN_EXT.M_C_REF = CURR.M_NumBer 
      )T 
on ( CURR.rowid = T.RID) 
when matched then 
update set CURR.MSYSTEM = 'S1' ;
```

Comment: Have you check if its already updated meaning if it is then theres no point running it again unless the records gets changed

Comment: I checked the results for the execution of last couple of days. I see S1 inserted in the column. However today, I tried to updated the colomn for a new entry, the merge query is executed nut no S1 inserted

Comment: Can you share the output result as well like new records and old updated records might help

Comment: Does the SELECT query there still return at least one row? Maybe someone deleted reference 123, so there is never a "when matched"

Comment: So, what changed since yesterday?

Comment: probem solved, issue was related to a wrong join in the query. Thank you all